# Shadow aliasing with ShaderMaterial on three.js

Tags: three.js, shadow

Here a picture of my problem, like you can see my shadows aren't smooth on my ShaderMaterial wich is a copy of PhongMaterial.

[image]

For the moment I have try all of these solution find on internet but nothing seems to work :

```
groundGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
groundGeometry.computeVertexNormals();
groundGeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFShadowMap; //And all options possible
renderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack; //And the other one
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias : true });
```

I also play with the different parameters of my SpotLight (also try with Directional light:

```
shadowMapWidth
shadowMapHeight
shadowCameraLeft
shadowCameraRight
shadowCameraBottom
shadowCameraTop
shadowCameraNear
shadowCameraFar
shadowBias
```

To be honest I don't know what to do now :/

So any help would be very appreciate !

Comment: do you mean your "copy of PhongMaterial" behaves different from actual PhongMaterial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is causes by self-shadowing. Try to set a small value of shadowBias like 0.05 or -0.05.

If your scene permits, reduce as much as possible the shadowmap frustum, changing the value of shadowCamera options to fit exactly the objects that you want.

If the angle between the light and normal at some point of the object is nearly 90 degrees, you can try to scale the bias depending of slope. There is an approach called *slope scaled bias* that consist in scale the bias depending of the angle between light vector and normal vector. The formula is:

```
float slope_bias = bias * tan(acos(dot(normal,-lightDirection)));
```

I hope it helps a little bit.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer !
It was at 0.001; I try 0.05 but nothing happened, and with -0.05 shadow disappear

Comment: Try (very patiently) to play with that parameter. I never find a way to set that value to look good at the first time. If 0.001 was good but not enough, try negative value

Comment: I've try very patiently to play with shadowBias but, it just make the shadow more or less visibles but still with my weird effect.
But I've change my shadowmap frustum (width shadowCameraRight/left/... right ?) and it seem that this parameters change nothing on the rendering (maybe a clue ? )

Comment: Two more things: what is the size of the shadowmap? Is the light too inclined respecr of the object?

Comment: Currently shadow map is a 1024 and yes the light is inclined like a sun in sunset ;)

Comment: Try the slope scaled bias method, that I described in the answer

Comment: Thanks for you reply but I don't really see how to implement this slope scaled method, in the shadow shader ? (I took it from the phong material). Otherwise I have tween my bias between -0.05 to 0.05 that make try about 3450 different value but no one seems to work

Comment: Yes you have to modify in the shader where shadow calculations are performed. With this method, the bias change depending on the slope of the geometry dinamically;  change it manually is different. See this ftp://download.nvidia.com/developer/presentations/2004/GPU_Jackpot/Shadow_Mapping.pdf